# A loop for VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have two big datasets in excel, 2k rows, 30 columns. It's an entry of employee shifts, one for January, the other for February.

The sets differ, because some employees have been hired, some left and some changed their shifts. I'm using VLOOKUP to check if a shift (the full time equivalent, like 50%) of a worker has changed in the last month.

This fails for workers with more than one shift, because VLOOKUP only goes for the first value it finds.

Here's an example.

[image]

And this is my formula.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(G22,C21:D25,2,0)=H22,"match","no match")
```

Now, if there is "no match" I want to trigger another IF, to see if the row below me has the same employee ID and if so, check if that's rows shift matches with what we have now.

The problem is I can't make the VLOOKUP lookup range static, because the dataset is too big.
Any ideas?

I tried using ROW, CHOOSEROW, HLOOKUP with VLOOKUP, LOOKUP and some others.

Comment: Research more: `MS365` --> `INDEX()`+`FILTER()`+`COUNTIFS()` or `Older Versions` --> `INDEX()`+`AGGREGATE()`+`COUNTIFS()` and do the comparison to return `match` or `no match` instead of `VLOOKUP()`. Lot of solutions posted here research more.

Comment: Use COUNTIFS to count if a specific ID and shift appears in the other dataset. If the count is 0, means no match, else match

Comment: Would you pls. show which column belongs to which column letter in your example?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, Jan and Feb ranges look the same to me. How do you calculate "no match" result?

Comment: @DataBunny They're getting the wrong result because the VLOOKUP is giving them the 60% (first found value) which isn't the same as 40%.

Comment: @Notus_Panda i see. then, FILTER() and if needed SORT() as mayukh-bhattacharya suggested at first.

Answer (score 1):

Information are kind of scarce, still paste this in a new sheet for a possible solution:

| Jan |  |  |  | Feb |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Id | shift |  |  | Id | shift | same as before? |
| 4545 | 1 |  |  | 4545 | 1 | `=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,E4)>0,IF(F4=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A:A)/(A:A=E4),COUNTIF($E$4:E4,E4))),"match","no match"),"new entry")` |
| 5959 | 0,6 |  |  | 5959 | 0,6 | `=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,E5)>0,IF(F5=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A:A)/(A:A=E5),COUNTIF($E$4:E5,E5))),"match","no match"),"new entry")` |
| 5959 | 0,4 |  |  | 5959 | 0,4 | `=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,E6)>0,IF(F6=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A:A)/(A:A=E6),COUNTIF($E$4:E6,E6))),"match","no match"),"new entry")` |
| 2598 | 1 |  |  | 2598 | 1 | `=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,E7)>0,IF(F7=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A:A)/(A:A=E7),COUNTIF($E$4:E7,E7))),"match","no match"),"new entry")` |
| 1313 | 0,7 |  |  | 1313 | 0,3 | `=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,E8)>0,IF(F8=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A:A)/(A:A=E8),COUNTIF($E$4:E8,E8))),"match","no match"),"new entry")` |
| 1313 | 0,3 |  |  | 7171 | 0,5 | `=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,E9)>0,IF(F9=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A:A)/(A:A=E9),COUNTIF($E$4:E9,E9))),"match","no match"),"new entry")` |

I had to guess that both lists are properly ordered so that the first occurence of an ID in january should be confronted with its first occurence in february, the second with the second... and so on.

Here the formula exploded:

```
=IF( ------------------------------------------------- Check if
    COUNTIF(                                           counting
            A:A,                                       in the range of previous month IDs
            E4                                         all those equal to the ID of the given row in this month
           )
    > 0                                                any is found
    ,
    IF( ---------------------------------------------- If any is found
       F4 = INDEX(                                     pick the shift of the given row in this month and compare it with a value
                  B:B,                                 in the range of previous month shifts
                  AGGREGATE(                           chosen via
                            15,                        picking the n smallest value
                            6,                         that is not an error
                            ROW(A:A) / (A:A=E4),       among the rows index of the previous month IDs range that contains the same ID of the given row in this month
                            COUNTIF(                   with n being equal to the count of the occurences
                                    $E$4:E4,           in the range of this month IDs
                                    E4                 of the ID of the given row in this month
                                   )
                           )
                 )
        ,
        "match" -------------------------------------- If the two shift values are the same, return "match"
        ,
        "no match" ----------------------------------- If the two shift values are not the same, return "no match"
      )
    ,
    "new entry" -------------------------------------- If no previous record of the given ID is found, return "new entry"
   )
```